# Simpifying boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need some help simplifying a boolean algebra expression.
$(~a*b*c*~d) + (a*~b*~c*~d) + (a*~b*c*~d) +(a*b*~c*d) + (a*b*c*~d)$
I have managed to simplify to $(~c*~d)*(~a+~b)+(a*b)*(~c*~d)+(a*~b*c*~d)$
but after this step, I manage to get a couple of *xor* gates which I don't understand how to use in order to simplify any further without getting several wrong answers.
I have tried the different results but they don't match the truth table. I would appreciate any help.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

$$a'bcd+ab'c'd+ab'cd'+abcd+abcd'$$
$$=(a'+a)bcd+(c'+c)ab'd+abcd'$$
$$=bcd+ab'd+abcd'$$
$$=bc(d+ad')+ab'd'$$
$$=bc(a+d)+ab'd'$$
$$=abc+bcd+ab'd'$$